# Running C# .exe Program in R, Getting Error 127

Tags: c#, r, visual-studio-2012

I made a console application in C#, and I want to execute it from R. I am trying to run the code `system(url)` where `url` is the location of the file in the directory `ApplicationPath/Bin/Debug`.

I get this error when I do it: `Warning message: running command ... had status 127`.

Do I need to compile my code in Visual Studio in a particular way to get it to run? It's worth noting that another console application that I made the exact same way (at least I thought) does work using this method. The only difference I notice is that in the Debug folder, the one that works has a Visual Studio Solution User Options file, and the other does not. I'm not sure if that makes a difference, but if so how do you create that?

Comment: Well, 127 means that the specified procedure could not be found..I'm thinking about a wrong syntax, or link or something like this..

Comment: This is the exact line that I'm using: `system("M:\\Eric\\Programs\\calculation\\calculation\\bin\\Debug\\calculation")`. calculation is the name of the program. The same syntax was used in the program that works.

Comment: Then copy the calculation file in R folder and run it again

Comment: Sorry, which folder do you mean by R folder?

Comment: Release? Is not that what you wanted to do?

Comment: haha yes, I just got caught up because in context "R" seemed to refer to folder that held the R programming language. anyway, tried that too and it didn't work.

Comment: Aaaa ok then. Have you tried to change the link syntax with "\" or "/" instead of "\\" ?

Comment: I have a solution: run it as `system(paste0(" cmd/K \"",url,"\""))`, which has it call the file from command prompt. This is more a workaround than an explanation of why what I was doing doesn't work, but at least now I have it working.

Comment: I see, well I'm glad then :)

Comment: @EricBrooks I have kind of the same issue. Would you mind having a look at my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431465/running-exe-from-r-status-127-warning-on-linux-not-on-windows)? Many thanks in advance.