# R Shiny error: could not find function "shell"

Tags: r, shell, shiny

My Shiny app works fine locally, but when I deploy it on shinyapps.io, I face the following error:

`Error: could not find function "shell"`

However, [shell](http://www.astrostatistics.psu.edu/datasets/R/html/base/html/shell.html) is an R built-in function (`base` package). So I don't really see what causes the error here and how to fix it?

Please see follow-up question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431465/running-exe-from-r-status-127-warning-on-linux-not-on-windows)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to remember that `shell` is a windows specific function. So, what probably happens is that you develop your app under windows, where `shell` works. However, when deploying the app probably runs under linux, where `shell` is not available. If you want to use system commands, I would use `system` in stead of `shell`.

Comment: right on. So if I use `system` instead of `shell` that should work on Linux?

Comment: when I replace `shell` by `system` it does not throw the error anymore but it raises a warning `Warning: running command foo.exe object had status 127` and it always output the same (faulty) results. Any thoughts?

Comment: from this [thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31595415/running-c-sharp-exe-program-in-r-getting-error-127) I just used `system(paste0(my_command))` and it worked...

Comment: I thought it was working, but I was wrong. Using system is probably the way to go though, but I still have to find the exact way to write/pass the command inside. Please see my new question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36431465/warning-running-command-had-status-127-when-trying-to-run-exe-from-r)