# running .exe from R: status 127 warning on Linux not on Windows

Tags: r, linux, windows, shiny

I'm calling an `.exe` from R using `system("script.exe object")`.

I get `Warning: running command had status 127`. I know it means the `.exe` file has not been found.

I'm on windows. When I use `shell` instead of `system` it works like a charm. However, I am designing a Shiny application that will be deployed in a Linux environment (shinyapps.io). This is why I need to use `system`.

**EDIT**

On Windows, it works with `system(paste("cmd.exe /c", "script.exe object"), intern = FALSE, wait = TRUE)` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5745886/r-and-system-calls/30802765#30802765). But not when I deploy the app (on Linux).

**HINT**

Locally on Windows, if I replace `system` with `system2`: `system2(paste("cmd.exe /c", "script.exe object"), wait = TRUE)`, it raises the `status 127` warning and the **output is exactly the same as in my deployed app on Linux**.

It's tough to create a reproducible example here but if needed I can try. Please tell me.

Context: basically the `.exe` is a black box (compiled C++ code) that takes a .txt file as input and outputs another .txt file. I am using R to dump the .txt file to the current working directory, then read back in the .txt file generated by the `.exe` (created in the current working directory, where the `.exe` file is stored).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem actually stemmed from the fact that `.exe` files are executables for Windows only. It does not work out of the box on Linux environments (you can use WINE but in my case it is not possible because I am calling the executable from within R, I don't have any `sudo` rights or anything on the virtual machine used by the host of my app). So I compiled the c++ code I had using g++ on a Linux virtual machine and used the `.out` file rather than the `.exe`.

Then in my R script I just needed these two calls:

`system("chmod a+x script.out") # to make Linux understand that the file is an executable`
`system("./script.out object") # to run the script`

Comment: It is good to see your application works. There is a wrapped build-in function `Sys.chmod`, which does (almost) the same thing.

Comment: thank you! in case you're interested this is the [app](https://safetyapp.shinyapps.io/GoWvis/). The c++ code is used for k_truss decomposition (under graph - mining - degeneracy)

Comment: This advice worked great for me, thanks! Like @yfyang said, the Sys.chmod function makes it bit neater but does the same thing

Answer (score 1):

Just add `\"` could solve you problem, e.g.

```
> setwd("W:/www/ADemo/")
> system(paste0(getwd(),"/Hi 2.exe"))
Hello, world.
> setwd("W:/www/A Demo/")
> system(paste0(getwd(),"/Hi 2.exe"))
Warning message:
running command 'W:/www/A Demo/Hi 2.exe' had status 127 
> system(paste0("\"",getwd(),"/Hi 2.exe","\" "))
Hello, world.
```

---

Update:
The 127 error is usually seen when there is a space in the path. One also needs to worry about the input of the application, e.g. `"/path A/A 2" --in-path "/home/A/B C/d 123.dta"`. Here are some update comments:

1. `system(shQuote(paste0(getwd(),"/Hi 2.exe")))` is much more convenient.
2. At least in R 3.2.4, the manual of `system()` recommends to use `system2()` instead to avoid path problem under Win/Linux/OSX/.

---

Update 2:
For Linux user, I created a function to detect the given file in your *working directory* is executable or not:

```
chkpermission<-function(file, mode='0777'){
 exe_list <- system("echo `ls -l | grep -E ^-.{2}x\\|^-.{5}x\\|^-.{8}x` | awk '{print $9}'", intern=T)
 if(length(exe_list)==0){
    stop("no file is executable");
    ##Make sure you know what you are doing here, add a+x permission:
    ##  if (!(file%in%exe_list)) Sys.chmod(file, mode = mode)
  }
 return(file%in%exe_list);
}
```

I've tested it on GNU awk/grep. The 2/5/8 indicates the executable permission of [u/2]ser, [g/5]roup, [o/8]thers., one could change it to meet the requirement.

Comment: thanks for your input. let me try and I'll get back to you

Comment: thanks for your help, but unfortunately none of your proposed solutions work for me. I will try to create a reproducible example and post it tomorrow